# Is there a way to consolidate these two queries into one in Cassandra/CQL? (group by workaround)

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have a table in Cassandra with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE test.top5(
timestamp timestamp,
category text,
term text,
volume int,
PRIMARY KEY(category, volume, term, timestamp)
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (volume DESC);
```

I am trying to get the Top 5 Searches per category. The volume column didn't originally need to be part of the composite key, but after reading about clustering in Cassandra (http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/create_table_r.html), I added it to the composite key so that it gets auto sorted by volume.

Since Cassandra does not support GROUP BY, the only way I am currently able to get the Top 5 Searches per category is with the following:

Query 1: `SELECT DISTINCT category FROM test.top5;`

Then, for each category:

Query 2: `SELECT term, volume FROM test.top5 WHERE category = thisCategory LIMIT 5;`

Is there a better or more efficient way to do this? I feel like there is going to be quite an overhead in terms of performance when working with a lot of data.